# Flask, Pandas, SQLITE3 passing datetime to HighCharts

Tags: python, json, datetime, highcharts, sqlite

I am using Flask and Pandas to read Datetime/Humidity from a SQLITE3 Database.  I am passing these values to a HighChart line graph.  I have tried everything from converting to CSV, to JSON but i cannot pass the datetime.  The humidity values pass correctly.

Here is my data pull:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("temphum.db")
dh = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT humidity from humidities limit 10', con)
dhd = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT rDatetime from humidities limit 10', con)
```

I Convert Humidity data into Highcharts usable string:

```
dhcsv = dh.ix[:,0].tolist()
```

I try to convert Datetime in correct syntax:

```
for i in dhd.index:
        dhd.loc[i, 'rDatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(dhd.loc[i, 'rDatetime'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

And then when I try to pass data to Highcharts and only Humidity is on the graph.
I can get close with this:

```
DHD2json = "','".join(map(str, dhd.ix[:,0].tolist()))
```

But html is showing that i am passing a string with leading and trailing quotes that i believe is causing my issue - (html var data that is being passed in below.)

```
var xAxis = {'categories': "2016-11-18 08:41:40','2016-11-18 08:44:08','2016-11-18 08:45:07','2016-11-18 08:46:10','2016-11-18 08:47:08','2016-11-18 08:48:08','2016-11-18 08:49:08','2016-11-18 08:50:05','2016-11-18 08:51:05','2016-11-18 08:52:11"}
```

Any constructive/instructional help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Highcharts is looking for a list of categories, rather than concatenating them all into a string:

```
var xAxis = {'categories': [map(str, dhd.ix[:,0].tolist())]}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  That did it.